# How to sign a rpm package without typing password?

Tags: linux, rpm, gnupg

I am trying to sign an RPM package that I created using GPG without typing the password, typing the password I can sign, however without typing the password is opening the message box `Please enter the passphrase to unlock the OpenPGP secret key`, I need the password not to be requested when signing the package, as this will be a script executed in "silent mode". I probably have the wrong command, but I'm having a hard time finding the solution.

This is the command I am trying to execute, and even then the password is requested:

`gpg --batch --passphrase "78910" --clearsign test-1-0.x86_64.rpm`

With this second command, the password is not requested:

`echo "78910" | gpg --batch --passphrase-fd 0  --clearsign test-1-0.x86_64.rpm`

However, the signature is not performed and returns the error described below:

`gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device gpg: /test-1-0.x86_64.rpm: clear-sign failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

With this third command, the reported error is different:

`echo "78910" | gpg --batch --passphrase-fd 0 ~/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg  --clearsign test-1-0.x86_64.rpm`

Error message:

`gpg: Note: '--clearsign' is not considered an option gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ... usage: gpg [options] [filename]`

This is my code to create the gpg key, i try create without password, but i receive error when the password value is empty.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Key-Type: 1" > gen-key-script
echo "Key-Length: 1024" >> gen-key-script
echo "Subkey-Type: 1" >> gen-key-script
echo "Subkey-Length: 1024" >> gen-key-script
echo "Name-Real: gpg test" >> gen-key-script
echo "Name-Email: test@test.com" >> gen-key-script
echo "Expire-Date: 0" >> gen-key-script
echo "Passphrase: 78910" >> gen-key-script
echo "" >> gen-key-script

#---------------------------------------------------------
# GENERATE THE KEY
#---------------------------------------------------------
gpg --batch --gen-key gen-key-script

#---------------------------------------------------------
# .RPMMACROS
#---------------------------------------------------------
echo "%_gpg_name gpg test <test@test.com>" > ~/.rpmmacros
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to type the password you'll need to store your private key on disk without being protected by a password. That means that everybody who has access to the key file can sign your packages. Decide if you want that.

---

If you don't want to protect the key use [`%no-protection`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Unattended-GPG-key-generation.html),  like this:

```
echo "%no-protection" > gen-key-script
echo "Key-Type: 1" >> gen-key-script
echo "Key-Length: 1024" >> gen-key-script
echo "Subkey-Type: 1" >> gen-key-script
echo "Subkey-Length: 1024" >> gen-key-script
echo "Name-Real: gpg test" >> gen-key-script
echo "Name-Email: test@test.com" >> gen-key-script
echo "Expire-Date: 0" >> gen-key-script
echo "" >> gen-key-script
```

Comment: I tried to create the key without a password, but since the script to create it occurs in "silent mode", I can not generate without the password field in the configuration file.

Comment: You can remove the password from the key afterwards

Comment: I did the tests with the indicated option, but I did not succeed, I also tried to use %no-ask-passphrase, but also to no success

Comment: Did you try the exact script as I've posted it? (plus the gpg command, sure). I've tested it. If you are also using GnuPG you might want to try to upgrade to a more recent version and/or check your settings in ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf (I'm using the default settings)

Comment: Thanks for helping to solve my problem, the error was occurring because the version of GnuPG installed on my system was outdated, I upgraded the version and it worked.

Comment: Cool! Nice to hear that.

Comment: @AlessandroCardoso could you please share how do you solve rpm asking for passphrase?

Comment: @OlegNeumyvakin to solve to find the solution for this problem verify my question and the answer of hek2mgl.
Make sure your GnuPG is in the latest version, in my case, the problem occurred because of the installed version of GnuPG, which was deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

**In case your GPG passphrase is empty:**

I am aware this is a bit late answer, but it works for me the best since I don't have GPG passphrase (**empty passphrase**). You can implement some techniques to pass it securely on CLI without typing it, anyway it you have empty passphrase I think this is a good solution.

```
echo "" | setsid rpmbuild -bb --sign <filename>.spec
```

SOURCE: https://rpm-list.redhat.narkive.com/7hkHM9bp/signing-rpms-without-a-passphrase#post4